# i want anyone can use my app and post messgae to my wall using my app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created an App using Facebook developer to post message in my wall.If i am logging in with my ID ,then I am able to post,but if I am logging in with some other id ,messages are not coming to my wall.
I have given all permissions as public,still other users are not able to post message.

Here is my code:

```
FB.login(function(){}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: "Hello"}
```

Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review). Without review, the `publish_actions` permission will only work for users with a role in the App.

Comment: I am new to Facebook development.Can you please guide how to use Login Review here in my code .

Comment: it´s not a code, you have to submit it to facebook. just open the link, everything you need to know is in the docs. it would be pointless to copy all the content from the link i added.